How to check packages installation dates through pip in Python?
How to check packages installation dates through pip in Python ?

First, you need to locate your package installation path:
python -m site --user-site

Then you can use this code:
import os
import time
from pathlib import Path
import site


site_packages_path = site.getsitepackages()[0]   # Assumes the first site-packages directory is the target

for package in Path(site_packages_path).iterdir():
    if package.is_dir():  # Filter out non-directory entries
        stat = package.stat()
        install_date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(stat.st_mtime))
        print(f"{package.name:30} Installed on: {install_date}")

